# android canvas.drawColor being called unexpectedly

Tags: android

I am creating a paint app.

In my program there is a variable named tool which stores the name of the tool being used.Initially it is set to free hand but when the tool is changed to any other tool and when I switch back the tool to free hand, then the screen get cleared with black color

.As a result I am unable to draw free hand but only a point appears following my finger.

I debugged the program and found that once the statement to clear the screen with black color is called, it gets called even when it not defined to be called.This is my piece of code:

```
  if(tool.equals("freeHand")){

         Log.d("free","move");
        try{
            canvas=null;
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

             synchronized (holder) {

                 //draw(canvas);
                 canvas2.drawBitmap(backup,0,0,paint);
                 canvas2.drawLine(startX, startY, moveX ,moveY, paint);
                 //backup=Bitmap.createBitmap(cache);
                 draw(canvas);

             }
            }finally{
             if(canvas != null){
              holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
             // backup=Bitmap.createBitmap(cache);
             }
            }
        //canvas2.drawLine(startX, startY, moveX ,moveY, paint);
        startX = moveX;
        startY = moveY;

        //backup=Bitmap.createBitmap(cache);

    }

     else{
         if(!tool.equals("freeHand") ){
            canvas2.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            Log.d("free", "bug");


         }

     if(tool=="line"){

        try{
            canvas=null;
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

             synchronized (holder) {

                 //draw(canvas);
                 canvas2.drawBitmap(backup,0,0,paint);
                 canvas2.drawLine(downX,downY,moveX,moveY, paint);
                 draw(canvas);

             }
            }finally{
             if(canvas != null){
              holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
             }
            }
        //canvas2.drawBitmap(backup, 0, 0, paint);
        //canvas2.drawLine(downX,downY,moveX,moveY, paint);


    }

     if(tool == "strokeRect"){

        try{
            canvas=null;
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

             synchronized (holder) {

                 //draw(canvas);
                 canvas2.drawBitmap(backup,0,0,paint);
                 canvas2.drawCircle(moveX, moveY, 20, paint);
                 draw(canvas);

             }
            }finally{
             if(canvas != null){
              holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
             }
            }

        //canvas2.drawCircle(moveX, moveY, 20, paint);
    }

     if(tool == "fillRect"){

        try{
            canvas=null;
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

             synchronized (holder) {

                 //draw(canvas);
                 canvas2.drawBitmap(backup,0,0,paint);
                 canvas2.drawRect(downX, downY, moveX, moveY, paint);   
                 draw(canvas);

             }
            }finally{
             if(canvas != null){
              holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
             }
            }


        //canvas2.drawRect(downX, downY, moveX, moveY, paint);  
    }
     if(tool=="img"){

            try{
                canvas=null;
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

                 synchronized (holder) {

                     //draw(canvas);
                     canvas2.drawBitmap(backup,0,0,paint);
                     canvas2.drawBitmap(img,moveX,moveY,paint);
                     //canvas2.drawBitmap(backup,0,0,paint);
                     draw(canvas);

                 }
                }finally{
                 if(canvas != null){
                  holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                 }
                }

        }

     }
```

I think that the statement:

```
canvas2.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
```

is causing the problem.

How do I get rid of unwanted call of the statement?

Comment: when you change the tool to something else the canvas goes black and you draw over it, what do you want to happen when you return to hand tool? do you want the background to be white again with everything still drawn over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare strings like this:

```
tool!="freeHand"
```

Strings are objects and `!=` tests if two objects are not the same object.

Instead, use the `equals()` method to test the contents of the strings:

```
!tool.equals("freeHand")
```

Because of "string interning", sometimes `!=` and `==` will work but you should not rely on it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

You might also consider not using strings.  How about an enum?

```
public enum Tool {Freehand, Eraser, Paintbrush }

...    

private Tool tool;

...

tool = Tool.Freehand;

...

if(tool == Tool.Freehand)
{
    ...
}
```

Much better...

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with the debugger to watch what happens?

Comment: yes, I even put another condition while checking to clear the screen and found that that once the screen clearing statement is called, it gets called on its own.

Comment: What do you mean, "gets called on it's own"?  It will only get called if your code calls it.  If you step through, you will see exactly what statements are being executed and why.  Please edit your post and show the code now you have fixed the problem with string comparison.

Comment: I had put a debug statement to notify me when the statement is called.I found that it is called for other tools except the free hand tool but still the screen gets cleared and as a result I cannot make a stroke but only a point appears on the screen following my finger movement.

Comment: Use the debuugger, not log statements, or you cannot see what's happening.  Put a breakpoint on the first line (`if(tool.equals(freeHand")`) then step through.

Comment: The debug tag "free" and message "bug" tells when the screen clearing statement is being called.It does not appear on the log when I use free hand tool but still the problem is not solved.

Comment: The absence of the message "bug" in the log shows that the statement is surely not being called but its effect is visible.I am telling that the this problem is being caused by this statement because when I do not call this statement then the free hand works perfectly but other tool do not have the effect of real time drawing.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you if you are going to ignore my advice.

Comment: I stepped through my code. I found that the that during the execution of the free hand tool, the same functions are called as during the first time when the free hand tool was called but the result of the first and the rest call were different.During the first call I was able to make stroke but after on I can make only  point that follows my finger movement.

Answer (score 0):

when you clear your screen using black color, it will clear everything on the screen, now even if you set the color to your original color, anything you drew earlier would not be visible, it will be overdrawn by the color.

> when I switch back the tool to free hand, then the screen get cleared
>   with black color

when you switch back , you have to set the color again, otherwise once set it will remain as it is